# Parsing a CSV using python's toolz package

Tags: python, csv, functional-programming, toolz

I recently came across the [toolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/) repository and decided to give it a spin.

Unfortunately, I’m having some trouble properly using it, or at least understanding it.

My first simple task for myself was to parse a tab separated TSV file and get the second column entry in it.

For example, given the file `foo.tsv`:

```
a    b    c
d    e    f
```

I’d like to return a list of `['b', 'e']`. I successfully achieved that with the following piece of logic

```
from toolz.curried import *

with open("foo.tsv", 'r') as f:
    data = pipe(f, map(str.rstrip),
                           map(str.split),
                           map(get(1)),
                           tuple)
    print(data)
```

However, if I change the `foo.tsv` file to use commas instead of tabs as the column delimiters I cannot seem to figure out the best way to adjust the above code to handle that. It’s not clear to me how to add best a `","` argument to the `str.split` function while using the `map` with either the `pipe` or `thread_first` functions.

Is there already some existing documentation that already describes this?

Comment: i would use `lambda x: x.split(',')` rather than `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### lambdas

Don't be afraid of using lambdas.

```
map(lambda s: s.split(','))
```

It's maybe a bit less pretty than `map(str.split)` but it gets the point across

#### Use pluck

Consider using `pluck(...)` rather than `map(get(...))`

```
map(get(1)) -> pluck(1)
```

#### Use Pandas

If you have a CSV file you might consider just using Pandas, which is very fast and highly optimized for this kind of work.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon [MRocklin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616616/mrocklin)'s above answer, my CSV parsing code using `toolz` should look more like:

```
with open("foo.tsv", 'r') as f:
    data = pipe(f, map(lambda (s): str.rstrip(s, "\n")),
                   map(lambda (s): str.split(s, "\t")),
                   pluck(1),
                   tuple)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version for the tsv file can be shortened to:

```
pipe(f, map(str.split), pluck(1), tuple)
```

To read a comma separated file, use something like this:

```
pipe(f, map(lambda s: s.split(',')), pluck(1), map(str.strip), tuple)
```